# Replace all but one occurrence of a character in a string

Tags: ios, swift, string

I have a string of numbers that may contain more than one decimal point because of user error.   Something like:

```
"2.3333.555.6664438"
```

I want to be able to remove all but one of the decimal points in the string (either the first or the last preferably):

```
"2.33335556664438"
```

or

```
"23333555.6664438"
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split into groups separated by the period character, and concatenate
all but the first group. Example (Swift 3):

```
var string = "2.3333.555.6664438"
let groups = string.components(separatedBy: ".")
if groups.count > 1 {
    string = groups[0] + "." + groups.dropFirst().joined()
}
print(string) // 2.33335556664438
```

Or: Find the first period character and remove all subsequent
occurrences:

```
var string = "2.3333.555.6664438"
if let r = string.range(of: ".") {
    string = string.substring(to: r.upperBound)
        + string.substring(from: r.upperBound).replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "")

}
print(string) // 2.33335556664438
```

(But note that the decimal separator is locale dependent and not necessarily the period character. For example, it is a comma in Germany.)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the String which can be also considered as an array of characters.... Set a flag so that you can keep one of the decimal points... Change the flag when your loop comes across one and toggle the flag.... So one of your decimal points is safe and still in the string.... Remove the rest wherever they come up....
Simple implementation of a loop and if else modules

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  I was just hoping there was a better way with a convenience method of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Martin R's solution to create a protocol extension. (Swift 2.3)

```
var string = "2.3333.555.6664438".removeDuplicateCharacters(".")

extension String {

  func removeDuplicateCharacters(input: String) -> String {
    let string = self
    var trimmedString = ""
    let preGroups = string.componentsSeparatedByString(input)
    if preGroups.count > 1 {
      trimmedString = preGroups[0] + input + preGroups.dropFirst().joinWithSeparator("")
      return trimmedString
    } else {
      return string
    }
  }
}
```